# Is there a way to disable linking on Passbook passes?

Tags: iphone, ios, passbook

I'm working on a pass for Passbook and we have a portion of data that is being linked as a phone number, but is actually a member number. Is there a way to indicate that a backfield in a pass should not be linked as a phone number? I'd love to disable this so we can properly format our data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read through Apple's documentation thoroughly but there was no mention of being able to disable that feature. I've specifically read: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW49

but there doesn't appear to be a way. I'm assuming I can't disable the functionality, but I wanted to see if anyone else has had better luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only numbers with seven or more digits are parsed as phone numbers as of 6.0.1:
[image: pass test]

Armed with this knowledge, we might append a zero width space (`\u200B`) to every sixth digit:
[image: fix]

It looks just fine. The only downside is the space splits the number when user copies it and for example google search returns results for `123456 789` as if the `zero width space` was a real space `\u20`.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me! I wasn't overly concerned about the copy/paste functionality and it was worth giving that up to have a properly rendered number. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Apple's data detection algorithms are quite aggressive and for the most part do a pretty poor job, particularly for non US addresses and telephone numbers.

There is no key you can set in pass.json to disable data detection. The only way we have found to prevent a number being converted is to prefix it with a #.

The # will also be rendered on the back of the pass, but the number will not be converted.

[image: Screenshot]